# Chrome loses cookies on browser restart

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I have cookies set to 'Allow local data to be set (recommended)' and yet, whenever I restart Chrome, I have to re-login to sites like reddit/facebook/google which should be keeping me logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that on those sites you select the "Remember Me" option, as websites can set an expiration time for the cookies, which is what appears to be happening here.

Comment: Of course, I do the exact same thing I do on my Windows computer. Yet, Chrome on the Mac doesn't keep sessions.

Comment: @thelsdj I've never experienced this problem with Chrome on the Mac.  What version are you using?  You can find this in the Chrome menu and then clicking on "About Google Chrome".

Comment: I've previously tried beta and dev channels and just tried Stable but that didn't seem to make a difference. One strange thing is some sites like Kickstarter and StackExchange work, but others like Google/Facebook/Reddit don't. All I can think to try now is trashing my entire Chrome profile to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Sometimes switching between Chrome builds could cause some profile issues.  I haven't heard of anyone else having this problem, so deleting your profile is probably a good idea.